# Is it okay to include a graduated phd student as a reference in resume/C.V?

Tags: phd, cv

I'm trying to apply for a PhD and want to include references in my resume. Is it okay to include a PhD student, one who has gotten a degree and has worked in our lab,and is currently working in industry, as a reference?

Comment: Has this PhD student completed their PhD or only earlier degrees and is still waiting to defend?

Comment: He had completed his PhD after defending his work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, they can, but consider whether they're the best choice:**

A referee needs to be your champion. A lab mate who you've never worked with probably can't do that, because they don't have a working relationship with you. Someone you've worked with can. (It's unclear which case applies here.)

Senior referees carry more clout than junior referees, so that's something to keep in mind.

Having referees from both industry and academia can be useful—it depends who the recipient is: A theoretician will surely be less interested in a referee from industry than someone more applied.

Comment: I have worked with him in the past, it's just that he completed his PhD about a year after I joined the lab.

Answer (score -2):

Why “former”? Has their PhD been revoked?

As to whether to include them, if they can vouch for your skills, abilities and/or experience then there is no reason why you should not include them.

Comment: Former in the sense, he isn't working in our lab any more. Maybe I should make it clearer. Thanks

Comment: @blazingcannon well, some people are awarded a doctorate for lifetime work and have never been a PhD student...